# Why my array's order is changing when i move the first item to the end

Tags: c#

I've made an app which is storing data about ip. Let's say my ip is changing every 1 minute. If I hadn't new ip before add it to textbox. If I -  had add `"Duplicate"` in textbox.

What I did is created a List of strings. The app is adding every `new_ip` variable to List. If it's unique, keep it. If it's not then delete first value of `List` and add `"Duplicate"` to `textBox`.

I don't know why my order is changing. The code is:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        new_ip = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    if (old_ip != new_ip)
    {
        ipList.Add(new_ip);

        if (ipList.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1))
        {
            ipList.Remove(ipList.First());
            ipList.Add("duplicate " + ile.ToString());
            ile++;
        }

        foreach (var name in ipList)
        {
            textBox1.Text += name + "\r\n";
        }
        textBox1.Text += "+---------------------+\r\n";
    }

    old_ip = new_ip;
}
```

Here's short example. Right order of ip should be:

```
11.111.111.111
duplicate 1
22.222.222.222
duplicate 2
33.333.333.333
44.444.444.444
```

But unfortunelly the app gave me this:

```
11.111.111.111
+---------------------+
11.111.111.111
22.222.222.222
+---------------------+
22.222.222.222   <--- what the hell happened there?
11.111.111.111   <--- that should be 1 row upper
duplicate 1
+---------------------+
11.111.111.111   <-- Hmm.. it seems to be fine somehow..
duplicate 1
22.222.222.222
duplicate 2
+---------------------+
11.111.111.111
duplicate 1
22.222.222.222
duplicate 2
33.333.333.333
+---------------------+
11.111.111.111
duplicate 1
22.222.222.222
duplicate 2
33.333.333.333
44.444.444.444
+---------------------+
```

does anybody have any idea where is the gaffe?

Comment: you are removing the first item from the list and then adding it again... did you try stepping through your code?

Comment: You're not deleting the first instance of the duplicate value, you're just deleting the first item from the list regardless of what it is.

Comment: Your GroupBy detects duplicates, but you don't remove the duplicates from the list. You remove the first item from the list, whether that's a duplicate or not. Try something like `var dupes = ipList.GroupBy(n => n).Where(c => c.Count() > 1);`. Really, you want to create a new list of non-duplicates, then append each duplicate to the new list with "Duplicate: " prefixed to each of those, and replace the old list with the new one. Much easier to think of it that way.

Comment: You are grouping, but you are never ordering, so your order is never guaranteed as is.

Comment: But the newest item added to the List isn't the first one from that List? I thought that is the main idea of listing o_o

Comment: Items added to a list go to the end of the list.  If you want it in the beginning, you would have to do an insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing first item, while you need to remove first occurrence of the item in the list:

```
var index = ipList.IndexOf(new_ip);
if(index >= 0)
   ipList.RemoveAt(index);
```

Also to check if the new ip exists in the list, you don't need a group by, you can simply use a [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

Comment: I added your code, but it's still reversing. Ill try with `Contains`

Comment: Here is the algorithm you should implement: *1)* Check for existence of new item. *2)* If exists, remove first occurrence. *3)* Add new item to the list.

Comment: @audiophonic It seems the post answers your question. Let me know if you have question about the answer or if you find it helpful :)

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot about that thread. I am thinking about something else right now. Of course you helped me a lot and I give you acceptance of answer right now :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, You're welcome.  You also have my vote :)

Answer (score 0):

just do something like

```
        Dictionary<string, int> ipList = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        if (!ipList.ContainsKey(new_ip))
        {
            // new ip that exists once.
            ipList.Add(new_ip, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            // dupliate ip - increment number of times duplicated
            ipList[new_ip] += 1;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> value in ipList)
        {
            textBox1.Text += string.Format(@"IP:{0} Duplicated: {1}\r\n", value.Key, value.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Unfirtunelly it does not count duplicates properly. It shows `0` every time no matter new ip existed before or not. What's more i had to delete `@` because `\r\n` doesnt make new row.

Comment: It should properly increment duplicates now ipList[new_ip] += 1